# Our systems have detected unusual traffic

Tags: error, censorship

YouTube is censored in my country and every time i open it in Tor i face below text and its take my time to pass human check . what can i do?

Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. Please try your request.

Answer (score 0):

See [Not allowed to sign in to Google when using Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20925/not-allowed-to-sign-in-to-google-when-using-tor)

You aren't doing anything wrong but Google doesn't like Tor users and will often block them. You have two options:

- Change your circuit and try again an hope that they accept the new
  exit node.
- Use a VPN. You will not have the advantages of Tor, but you will
  probably be able to access Google services.

Answer (score 0):

When this persists, you can bypass it by clicking the button "New Tor Circuit for this Site". You get a new IP address each time you click the button, eventually one of those IP addresses will work.

I made an extension https://gitlab.torproject.org/lansi90/google-captcha-bypass-extension that deals with this issue transparently. Since I started using it, I do not encounter this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The "unusual traffic" is not from you, but from your ExitNode - and it includes **all** the users that are using it as an exit. Big phishing corporation like Google are stealing your privacy and do not make the dot-onion endpoints for their services because they do want to steal your data and sell it to the advertisers. Facebook is the only one big corporation now - as to my knowledge - who've made a green HTTPS dot-onion for their system **and** added Tor option to the settings of their mobile application(at least it was on Android I used to use) - check https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/ It's not your guilty or problem - it's their bad intentions to track and pinpoint you